# Scala / How to remove duplicates of an array of tuples based on two values?

Tags: arrays, scala, duplicates, distinct

I have an array with millions of tuple elements like:

```
var arr: ArrayBuffer[(String, String)] = ArrayBuffer[(String, String)]()
arr += (("Hamburg", "Street1"))
arr += (("Hamburg", "Street2"))
arr += (("Hamburg", "Street1")) // duplicate - remove
arr += (("Berlin",  "StreetA"))
arr += (("Berlin",  "StreetZ"))
arr += (("Berlin",  "StreetZ")) // duplicate - remove
arr += (("Berlin",  "StreetA")) // duplicate - remove
```

**I would now like to have those duplicates within that array removed, where City AND Street are equal.**
Something like:

```
arr.distinctBy(_._1&_._2) // doesn't work just for illustration
```

Is there a simple solution to it, how this can be done to get an output like:

```
(("Hamburg", "Street1"))
(("Hamburg", "Street2"))
(("Berlin",  "StreetA"))
(("Berlin",  "StreetZ"))
```

Comment: You may see if you could have saved all the mutability and array buffer from the beginning and just have created a `Set` right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `equals` and `hashCode` are overridden for tuples you can use [`distinct`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/collection/Seq.html#distinct:C) which is effectively is `distinctBy(identity)`:

```scala
val result = arr.distinct
```

Answer (score 3):

Calling `arr.toSet` on your array will do what you require:

```
arr.toSet 
res34: Set[(String, String)] = Set(
  ("Hamburg", "Street1"),
  ("Hamburg", "Street2"),
  ("Berlin", "StreetA"),
  ("Berlin", "StreetZ")
)
```

Tuples are [case classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/case-classes.html#equals-and-hashcode-methods), so are provided with `equals` and `hashCode` methods to support comparisons.

If your use case is to ensure a collection contains no duplicates, you should generally use a `set`. This allows other readers of your code to infer that there are no duplicates in the collection.

Comment: Might be worth explaining why, meaning how equality is defined for tuples.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation @GaëlJ, I've done as you suggested.